# How to you detect which input device is being used in MS Access?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I've tried googling this but all the search results are on how to detect a device period, not how to detect which input device is being used.

I have a barcode scanner we're using to check-in patrons to our swimming pool, and I want to design a database that will detect when the scanner is being used and automatically open a form before entering the input. For example: if the database is open, but not in the appropriate form, or not highlighting the appropriate field, as soon as the database detects that an incoming input is coming from the barcode scanner, it will open the form and enter the input into the approriate field.

I understand that barcode sensors are in essence keyboards, but is there a way I can detect *which* keyboard an input id coming from and if it's a specific one, then run a sub before it writes the input?

```
IF input is from barcode scanner THEN
DoCmd.OpenForm "CheckIn" 
DoCmd.GoToControl "ScanBarcode"
```

Comment: AFAIK a barcode scanner is just a fancypants keyboard. You're going to have to get real close to the metal to figure that one out. Probably not worth it. Why not make a "Scan" button that the user can click to bring up the "scanner form"?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have one of those. I'm just trying to idiot proof this thing as much as possible. Hard to do when the idiot bar is placed lower and lower every year...

Comment: There certainly is no generic way to detect barcode readers.  You could probably create a barcode for people to scan that will send some kind of keyboard input to load the correct form.

Comment: I'm looking at the properties for the scanner, and it has things like, "Device Instance Path" (HID\VID_13BA&PID_0018\6&AA80C36&0&0000), "Physical Divice Object Name" (\Device\0000008c), "Container ID" ({994f3c35-e18c-11e6-9438-1cc1deb38074}) I feel like one of these might be usable in VBA to identify the barcode scanner.

Comment: @Zoredache Like a shortcut key to open the form eh? I'm using Code 39, not sure what type of encoder I'd need to make barcodes like that.

Comment: [This might get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36240342/4088852).

Comment: Hmmm...I only thought that M$ Access was a database program.